Need to convert Adobe premiere project files from *.ppj to *.prproj, that is can I upgrade the file to open in Adobe PremierePro 2023
I have tried to access an early version of Premiere, but failed. The current file structure (*.ppj) of my older projects (pre-CS6) is not supported in any of the PremierePro suite, but fundamentally the .ppj file is, or appears to be, similar to an xml. Is there a method of changing the file so that it can be read in either PremierePro 2023 or Da Vinci Resolve 18?
